How to use a JSON String inside a docker-compose.yml file
I always get this error
yaml: line XX: mapping values are not allowed in this context
this is the part of my yaml file (for zabbix)
  web-nginx:
    image: 'zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql:alpine-trunk'
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      ZBX_SERVER_HOST=xxx
      DB_SERVER_HOST=xxx
      POSTGRES_USER=xxx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
      POSTGRES_DB=xxx
      PHP_TZ=xxx
      ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS="{\"strict\": false, \"baseurl\": \"https://xxx\", \"use_proxy_headers\": true}"

I already tried atleast these combinations

ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS="{"strict": false, "baseurl": "https://xxx", "use_proxy_headers": true}"
"ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS={"strict": false, "baseurl": "https://xxx", "use_proxy_headers": true}"
ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS='{"strict": false, "baseurl": "https://xxx", "use_proxy_headers": true}'


You used = instead of : in the last block.

either
ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS:'{"strict": false, "baseurl": "https://xxx", "use_proxy_headers": true}'
or
ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS:"{\"strict\": false, \"baseurl\": \"https://xxx\", \"use_proxy_headers\": true}"
does not work still giving me the  mapping values are not allowed in this context

Did you fix the other lines as well?

using - ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS="{\"strict\":false,\"baseurl\":\"https://xxx\",\"use_proxy_headers\":true}"
fixed the issue, so using -, =, escaping " and removing the spaces of the json
probably because yaml is space dependent?

using
- ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS="{\"strict\":false,\"baseurl\":\"https://xxx\",\"use_proxy_headers\":true}"
fixed the issue, so using -, =, escaping " and removing the spaces of the json
probably because yaml is space dependent?

I'd make two changes here.
Compose environment: has two syntaxes.  It either needs to be a YAML list (- KEY=value) or a mapping (KEY: value).  The format you have with multiple lines of KEY=value won't work.  I'd choose the mapping syntax here
environment:
  ZBX_SERVER_HOST: xxx
  DB_SERVER_HOST: xxx
                ^^ note, colons and not equals signs here

In this syntax, the keys and values are separate YAML scalars.  This means you can use YAML block scalar syntax.  If a key has no value except that it ends with | (with some optional whitespace controls) and the following lines are indented, then those following lines are read as a multi-line string.  The part that is the string is identified by it being indented, so there is no more quoting or escaping required.  > is similar except that newlines are converted to spaces.
So if you directly needed to pass a JSON object string in an environment variable, you might do it as a YAML block scalar
environment:
  ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS: >-
    {"strict": false, "baseurl": "https://xxx", "use_proxy_headers": true}

With the > form, you can also optionally split this out across multiple lines, and they'll be joined and separated by spaces.
environment:
  ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS: >-
    {
      "strict": false,
      "baseurl": "https://xxx",
      "use_proxy_headers": true
    }


My SSO_SETTINGS started working correctly only like this:
 environment:
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
  - MYSQL_USER=zabbix
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=zabbix
  - ZBX_SERVER_NAME=Zabbix 7.0.2
  - PHP_TZ=America/Phoenix
  - >-
    ZBX_SSO_SETTINGS={"strict": false, "baseurl": "https://xxxxx", "use_proxy_headers": true, "security": {"requestedAuthnContext": false}}

